# AngularJs: How to interpolate an interpolated string?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, interpolation, string-interpolation

I'm trying to Interpolate a string coming from a database which looks like this `"Users({{users_count || 0}})"`, and when I interpolate it using `{{}}` or `ng-bind` it doesn't get interpolated, because in the HTML I write `{{data.usersCount}}` and the page interpolates the data as text not as js, (what I intended the page to render is `Users(8)`, and what gets rendered is `Users({{users_count || 0}})`).
So my question is how to interpolate the string that was interpolated from the `usersCount` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate), as in

```
$interpolate("Users({{users_count || 0}})")($scope)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. by adding this in the js controller and interpolating the string in the HTML it works!